# SQL queries- 2nd largest number

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, mysql-python

Using sql, how can I  find the second largest number through a query?

Comment: `SELECT ~0 - 1;` ;-)

Comment: I'm thinking that this question is usefully because it's simple but specific...

Answer (score 2):

or use limit:

```
SELECT number
FROM numbers
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY number DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aed1/1

```
SELECT MAX(number) FROM test WHERE number < (SELECT MAX(number) FROM test )
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd largest use this:-

```
SELECT MAX(num) FROM TABLE
  WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT MAX(num) FROM Employee)
```

If you need to use it in generic way, then use this to get Nth largest number

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM TABLE table1
WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table2.num))
FROM TABLE table2
WHERE table2.num > table1.num)
```

So using above query, if u want to find second largest then query changes to...

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM TABLE table1
WHERE 1 = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(table2.num))
FROM TABLE table2
WHERE table2.num > table1.num)
```